# Problem with InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have such a year

```
import React,{InputHTMLAttributes} from "react";

export interface faceTegInput extends InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
  readonly Tag: string;
  readonly key: string;
}

export const inputSetSearch: faceTegInput = {
  type: "text",
  size: 50,
  maxLength: 150,
  placeholder: "Search for anything",
  alt: "search",
  spellCheck: false,
  autoComplete: "off"
};
```

I get this error
Type '{ type: string; size: number; maxLength: number; placeholder: string; alt: string; spellCheck: false; autoComplete: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'faceTegInput': Tag, key.
What is the reason I can not understand.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not providing `Tag` and `key` in `inputSetSearch`. You should whether add them to the `inputSetSearch` or make them optional.

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/embed/n7wnx5xjl0)